# unsigned int(32bit) to unsigned long long (64bit)

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, unsigned-long-long-int

In the code below, I multiplied `0xffffffff` by 2 for an `unsigned int`(32bit) and stored it in a `unsigned long long`(64bit). Why don't I get the actual output which is `8589934588`. Instead I get `4294967294`.
    Thanks in advance.
    OUTPUT:
    Sizeof i=4
    Sizeof J=8
    2xi=4294967292

```
/* Code starts here */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) 
{
    unsigned int i=4294967294;
    unsigned long long j=i*2;
    printf("Sizeof i=%d\n", sizeof(i));
    printf("Sizeof J=%d\n", sizeof(j));
    printf("2xi=%llu\n", j);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the `i*2` is integer multiply. Even though you're storing it in a `long long`, you're still doing integer math, which causes an overflow.

The following code works, as we promote it up to `long long` multiply

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
  unsigned int i=4294967294;
  unsigned long long j=((unsigned long long)i)*2;
  printf("Sizeof i=%d\n", sizeof(i));
  printf("Sizeof J=%d\n", sizeof(j));
  printf("2xi=%llu\n", j);

  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
bash-4.1$ gcc long.c
bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Sizeof i=4
Sizeof J=8
2xi=8589934588
```

Comment: Keep in mind `signed overflow` is undefined behavior but unsigned overflow just wraps.

Answer (score 3):

`i*2` knows nothing about the fact that it's being assigned to an `unsigned long long` - since `i` is an `unsigned int` and `2` is an `int` the multiplication is performed using the `unsigned int` type, which yields the result you got.

You can fix the problem by making `2` an `unsigned long long` literal, which promotes `i` to `unsigned long long` for the multiplication, or casting `i` to `unsigned long long` before the multiplication, which has the same effect:

```
unsigned long long j=i*2ULL;
/* or */
unsigned long long j=((unsigned long long)i)*2;
```

---

In general, remember: in C the target of an assignment/initialization does not affect how the expression to its right is computed - the types involved are determined only by the types of the operands.

Answer (score 2):

Since `i` is an `unsigned int` and `2` is an `int` and will be promoted to `unsigned int` the operation will just wrap around. One solution would be to cast `i` to `unsigned long long`:

```
unsigned long long j = ((unsigned long long)i)*2 ;
```

The relevant section from the [draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is in `6.2.5/9`:

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
>   because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
>   represented by the resulting type.